# What is the translation of my guild’s name?

Tags: translation

I started playing a game and joined a Chinese guild (luckily there is a rough built in translator for chat).

Below pictured is my guild name

[image: Guild Name]

I attempted to get the correct characters which I think are 有妖气客栈.

I was told by, who I believe is an English/Chinese speaker in the guild that this translates to "Tavern of Hex". If this is true, does anyone know what this is or its reference?

From the characters that I have (有妖气客栈), I placed these in google translate and it gave me "Have a demon hotel".  Again, strange for only English speaker, but contradicts what I was told.

What is the correct translation and meaning of my guild’s name?

Comment: 有妖气（reads you yao qi）（u17）（reads the same in Chinese）is an original comic installment website. 客栈 is tavern.

Comment: 妖气 is literally "the aura of demons and monsters" 有 means "there be"

Comment: 有妖气 is the name of 客栈, a hotel(usually decorated as antique style) named “YǒuYāoQì”, which literally means "There is the aura of demons or monsters".

Comment: It's the same as "Hotel California" Get the words of the song and you will know what I mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

有妖气 is a reference to the comic 十万个冷笑话(100 thousand bad jokes), where 有妖气 is a running gag, literally translates to "there is evil spirit" or like Toosky said, "there is an aura of demons", 客栈 is "Tavern"

The name of the Tavern is called "有妖气", so the best translation is:

**"There is evil spirit" Tavern**

**Correction: Based on the comment, "There is demon aura" is the more appropriate translation**

Comment: "There is evil spirit" imply evil spirit is present. I suggest ["There is demon aura" Tavern] would be more accurate. You only sense the aura of the demon. The demon itself may or may not currently present. I meant even the demon left, it's aura would persist for a period of time. Just like smell of an animal can be detected,  even the animal is not currently occupying the den

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I'm wrong. Will "**Tavern hovering with daemon aura**" or "**The Daemon-Aura-Hovered Tavern**" make sense in English?

Comment: I think "daemon-haunted tavern" (or even just "haunted tavern") would be simplest.